# Overpass query does not return values after changing the bounding box parameters

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I have a very weird situation with 2 almost identical queries to Overpass Turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/DhG

The only difference between the two are divergent values for the bounding box.
How is that possible?

Working bounding box values: (47.47025512626575,8.29673767089844,47.484757928976975,8.31819534301758);

Not working bounding box values:
(47.47892465783725,8.303614854812624,47.480737427990285,8.306297063827516);

Comment: Please describe what "unexpectedly" is supposed to mean. Describe your expected and actual results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Damn, I'm stupid! The second bounding box is simply too small. Nothing to find!

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/149651)

Comment: This already is the answer. I found the problem right after sending the question out. I can only mark it as correct answer in a few days.

Comment: @MarkIreland or is it better to delete such a question altogether. Maybe not very useful for other people?

Comment: Yes, probably better to delete altogether. As you say it's not very useful for other people. I flagged the answer in review for this reason and "this should be a question edit" was the nearest option (we have a checklist of reasons to choose from) that applied.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to delete. "Question could be useful for others" was the message...